# selenium send_keys('123456') results in randomized order

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Assume the number is: `1111 2222 3333 4444`

I tried to use `driver.send_keys(number)` to fill a field of number. However, it seems like the website is doing some randomization of the number entered. 
The field is supposed to have numbers entered one digit at once, for example, it's not going to be '1 2345678'.

Is there any way that I can solve this problem? I thought all I had to do is to cut the number in half with '11112222' and '33334444' and enter them reversely and it has been working for a few times. However, right now it's starting to randomize the order again IN SECTION of four numbers : (sample output) `2222 3333 4444 1111` and the order I want them to be is `1111 2222 3333 4444`.

Could anyone help me with this please? Never seen this randomization on HTML before..

---

The website is this : https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout (Have to add something and click checkout)
My code is as followed:

```
number1 = "12345678"
number2 = '90111213'  



driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='credit_card[cnb]']").send_keys(number2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='credit_card[cnb]']").send_keys(number1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up ! I just added on the description. Please have a look! @JeffC